# DataGridView filtering method does not work correctly when a button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

I know I asked this question already many times, but I did not get answer which can help me.

Please, need advice I already trying to do this 1 week or more.

I have a user control where my `DataGrid` is.  There is a `toolBar` with a button that opens a `Find` form that has one button and one `textBox`. On this button click, I call method `Search()` like this :

```cs
private void btnFind_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Inventory i = new Inventory();
    i.Search(txtFind.Text);
}
```

and this is how the method `Search` works :

```cs
public void Search(string searchWord) 
{
    AcidDBDataContext db = new AcidDBDataContext();
    var q = db.ProcSearch(searchWord);
    dgvInventory.DataSource = q;
}
```

This method works fine in inventory but when I click `btnFind`, it doing nothing, I used a debugger and saw that query is executing correctly and gets rows from table.

Problem is on this line : `dgvInventory.DataSource = q;`

I'm using C# WinForms and SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a BindingSource

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
```

and then in Search(string searchWord)

```
//dgvInventory.DataSource = q;
bs.DataSource = q;
if (dgvInventory.DataSource == null)
    dgvInventory.DataSource = bs;
else
    bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

Comment: it does not works. I even cannot hide datagrid column from another form

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried dgvInventory.ResetBindings()?

*[Edit: mistakenly stated .Refresh instead of .ResetBindings]*

Comment: I tried it now but does not works. Does not work anything on datagridview from another form

Comment: Actually it was ResetBindings() I was thinking of as mentioned by cdel above. I think Refresh is aimed at the UI representation.